# Are there any use cases for supporting zone ids for public ipv6 addresses?

Tags: ipv6

I am testing a product made by a vendor for communicating with external servers with public IP addresses. When testing the product I noticed that IPV6 addresses with [zone ids](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6874), e.g.

```
2001:4860:4860::8888%eth0
```

are not supported. **Are there any real-world use cases, where zone ids are used in non-local networks for IPV6 addresses?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [RFC 4007](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4007#section-5) there is only one global zone:

> There is a single zone of global scope (for both unicast and
> multicast) comprising all the links and interfaces in the
> Internet.

So if you want to reach a destination in the global scope then there is only one zone to use anyway.